# How to delete vssver2.scc and global.asax from my Windows Server?

Tags: file-permissions

I have a Windows server that I SFTP into, and I have some very old vssver2.scc files on there. They are used by Visual Source Safe- which is no longer used (SVN instead now). I want to delete them.

Most troubling though is a very old global.asax file used by ASP.NET applications - since the app is compiled, it reads from it's global.dll in the Bin folder, and not the global.asax. I want to get rid of it. But I can't - and I can't overwrite it in favor of a newer one either.

These files have 444 (Owner:r Group:r Public:r) permission and when I try to give them 777 (O:rwx G:rwx P:rwx) permission hoping it will let me delete them, it goes back to 444.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's some sort of wierd permissions issue. Since the sysadmins won't fix it and don't know what the issue is, whenever I have this problem, I just bug them to delete the files I need.

Answer (score 2):

In the root directory write the following:

```
attrib -s -h -r *.?cc /s
del *.?cc /s
```

Comment: Just used this method to remove a load of old Visual SourceSafe (*.scc) files - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have physical access to the server, you can boot a live cd like [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.org/) and from there navigate over to your drive to delete those files.